# R - Remove silvers by snapping polygon layer to another

Tags: r, polygon, shapefile, r-sf, qgis

I have 2 polygons in separate files: a hand-digitized boundary (blue) & the county shapefile (red). My goal is to find out which counties the boundary intersects. However, some parts of the boundary do not align with the county boundary (due to silvers that are not snapped) so my results returned counties that were not supposed to be included.

[Example of my explaination: the county boundary on the top is included when it's shouldn't be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux8xl.png)

I'm trying to snap the polygon to the county boundary so that the nearest points in the polygon aligns with the county boundary and then I will use `st.intersect()` to retrieve the names of the intersecting boundary.

I tried using `st.snap` but it is giving me an error.

```
county <- st_transform(county, 4269) # CRS to (EPSG:4269)
p <- st_transform(p, 4269)
snapped <- st_snap(p, county, 1000)

# Error in st_snap.sfc(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y), tolerance) : 
#  st_snap for longitude/latitude data not supported; use st_transform first?
```

I'm basically trying to perform what [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340178/snapping-polygon-layer-to-another-layer-automatically/384574#384574) is explaining but in R, preferebly with the sf package.

Any help would be great. Please let me know if there are any clarifications needed.

Comment: While it is difficult to make sure just going by your description I believe that `sf::st_snap()` may be of help in your use case.

Comment: @JindraLacko I just updated my post but I tried using that and an error came up.

Comment: Did you transform the shape to non longitude/latitude coordinates like the error message says to do? Also within the code you've posted here, you didn't define `p`, so it's unclear what that actually is